# Scala pattern matching against something of multiple types

Tags: scala

Suppose `c` can be `Updatable` or `Drawable` or *both*. If it's *both*, I want to handle `Updatable` first.

Given this code:

```scala
case c: Updatable => c.update()
case c: Drawable => c.draw()
```

Has one problem: it only evaluates one of the choices. Sometimes, `c` can be both so I need to run both of these.

I know there's `|` mechanism that looks like this:

```scala
case c @ (_: Updatable | _: Drawable) => c.update(); c.draw()
```

The problem here is that I can't call both `update` and `draw` because it's an `|`.

I think I'm looking for something like this, but doesn't compile:

```scala
case c @ (_: Updatable & _: Drawable) => c.update(); c.draw()
case c: Updatable => c.update()
case c: Drawable => c.draw()
```

Is there such a thing? I know I could open it up and write `isInstacenOf`, but I'd prefer a pattern match if it's even possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def f(c:Any) = c match {
  case d:Drawable with Updatable => println("both")
  case d:Drawable => println("drawable")
  case u:Updatable => println("updatable")
}
```

Comment: This is a fantastic idea, why did I not think of this? ;)

Comment: The `with` keyword used in this context is conjunction (obviously). If you're interested in disjunctive / union types, check out this fantastic blog: http://www.chuusai.com/2011/06/09/scala-union-types-curry-howard/

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

```
trait Foo
trait Bar
class FooBarImpl extends Foo with Bar
type FooBar = Foo with Bar


def matching(x: Any) = x match {
    case _: FooBar  => "i'm both of them"
    case _: Foo    => "i'm foo"
    case _: Bar    => "i'm bar"
}

val x = new FooBarImpl

matching(x) 
// res0: String = i'm both of them
matching(new Foo{})
// res1: String = i'm foo
```

Although I'm not quite sure whether reflection kicks in or not.

Comment: I think defining the union type is nice if you need to pattern match like this often, but for 1 single case I'm going with what Landei showed.

Comment: @KaiSellgren nothing stops you from writing `case _: Foo with Bar` without defining any external type alias ;-)

Comment: That is correct. Your answer is basically the same as what Landei did there. I happened to accept his answer due to the angle of the moon.

Comment: "Union" is a very poor choice for this construct. Union is typically interpreted as disjunctive while `with` is conjunctive.